# UWP on W. IoT storing data permanently

Tags: .net, uwp, windowsiot

The setup:

> Raspberry Pi3 with Windows 10 IoT.
>
> Visual Studio (with VB).
>
> The app is a simple background application.

I use "Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path" folder for save the SQLite .net file . But when I switch from Debug to Release the application folder is deleted. It is normal, ok.

**But there is an alternative folder without limit of space and permissions to save the database file?**

*It is an internal project without too much trouble for the security, and will not be published, so I do not mind sharing with other apps, and are not sensible data.*

---

**THE DB CLASS**

```
Public Class SQLLite

    <Table("TABLE_TEMP")>
    Private Class TABLE_TEMP

        <PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement>
        Public Property ID As Integer
        Public Property temp As Double
        Public Property humidity As Integer
        Public Property relay As Integer
        Public Property data As DateTime

    End Class

    Private conn As SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection

    Sub New(_path As String)

        '### THIS WORK      
        'Dim Path As String = Path.Concat(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "\db.sqlite")

        '### THIS NOT WORK
        Dim Path As String = Path.Concat(_path, "\db.sqlite") 

        conn = New SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(New SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), Path, False)
        Try

            Dim result As String = conn.ExecuteScalar(Of String)("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='TABLE_TEMP'")
            If result <> "TABLE_TEMP" Then
                conn.CreateTable(Of TABLE_TEMP)()
            End If

        Catch exsql As SQLite.Net.SQLiteException
            Debug.WriteLine("EX_SQL: " & exsql.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("EX: " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    .
    .
    .
    ' OTHER DB FUNCTIONS
    .
    .
    .
End Class
```

**THE CALL TO DB CLASS**

```
Dim f As Windows.Storage.StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary
Dim musicLibrary = Await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Music)

Dim dbSqlLite As New WIoTLibrary.SQLLite(musicLibrary.SaveFolder.Path)
```

*For work you need the NuGet Package **SQLite.Net-PCL***

Comment: Generally your data in *LocalFolder* should persist, between separate runs of the app and its updates. As for other folders as an alternative - have you thought about using the ones from [KnownFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx)? You can also ask the user on the very fist run to pick a folder for the picker and then remember if for future runs.

Comment: @Romasz Unfortunately it does not seem to work. I tried "DocumentsLibrary" but it is no longer accessible. I tried the "PicturesLibrary" but even this did not work, I can not retrieve the real path of the virtual folder (here the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874259/windows-storage-knownfolders-musiclibrary-path-returns-empty?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: To use those KnownFolders you have to add capabilities in manifest file - have you done that? Are you trying to access folders by path? Can you just use StorageFolders for your purpose?

Comment: @Romasz 1) Yes. 2) How? I tried the code at the end of the linked answer. The async method "StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync" but it does not work. 3) Which folders can I browse with StorageFolder? The most banal thing I expected was to be able to browse the entire filesystem (obviously enabling the permissions), but I don't know how. Thanks for the support :)

Comment: On UWP the app doesn't have privileges to browse the filesystem, it must be granted by user - either by accepting capabilities or by using file/folder picker (of course we talk about official API). As for accessing known folder - you should be able to get such like this: `StorageFolder musicFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;`

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know why but it does not seem to want to save the database file "db.sqlite", it gives me this error: `'SQLite.Net.SQLiteException' in SQLite.Net.dll`. I obviously enabled the capabilities.

Comment: Is it possible you can share a minimal sample project that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, but will not work alone, the project is more complex. This is a background app with web server that save data on SQLite .net. I try to extrapolate the interesting section.

Comment: Can you create a sample project with dummy sql database which you try to save?

Comment: While updating the answer, I realized that it is too much work for you !! The NuGet package created me several problems to make it work. If I have a moment, I try to do a small working project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134928/discussion-between-romasz-and-baro).

Comment: @Baro, check out the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009016/sqlite-net-wont-create-in-win-iot-library, hope it helps.

Comment: @Jackie Great ! work !! From debug to realse the DB not been deleted. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jackie After some other test I can say that: The db file not persist from debug to release ! Thanks anyway.